# Laravel how to check if file successful uploaded?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, file-upload

I wonder if I'm using a ValidationController to validate the file upload and have this in my UploadController:

```
$file = $request->validated();
```

right before this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file') {
  $file = $request->file('file');
  if ($file->isValid()) {
    [...]
  }
}
```

**is it even necessary to do `$request->hasFile('file')`-block?**

In the ValidationController I already set the validation rules that the file is required and has to be a pdf, so `hasFile('file')` is probably redundant. If the file would not have been uploaded then I would get redirected by the validator.

I know the `$file->isValid()`part checks if the file has been uploaded successfully, so this might be necessary even after the validation pf the file.

Comment: Please check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909833/how-to-check-file-is-uploaded-or-not-in-laravel

Comment: @DilipHirapara this doesn't answer my question, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

> is it even necessary to do `$request->hasFile('file')`-block?

The main question will be whether this logic executes in scenarios where `$request` does *not* have a file called `file`.

Without the `hasFile` call, a request that's lacking a file in `file` will throw an error ("Call to a member function isValid() on null") on the line `$file->isValid()`, as `$file` will be null.

Comment: But if there is no file uploaded I will get redirected to the form   by the line '$file = $request->validated()' since the validation rule for this field is to be required, so this block wouldn't get executed anymore, that's what I'm trying to ask

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon You haven't included your validation rules in the question, hence my caution in how I explained things. If you've tested that validation and are comfortable with it, I'd say you can ditch the `hasFile` conditional.

Comment: I haven't included them but written it's required, didn't want another code piece to be there. Thanks for your answer though. I just wasn't sure if this block is redundant after the validation..

Comment: If your validation correctly enforces that a file is present - your validation rules should include **both** `required` and `file` rules - then it's redundant.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to run `php artisan storage:link` in your Laravel Folder to set a storage link in your Laravel App.
The Validator will help you to know if the file is uploaded.

And the hasFile function checks if the file is uploaded so via the method we can check if the file is successfully uploaded and you can have a alert for User convienient webapp.

```
    public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
    ]);
    // Handle File Upload
    if($request->hasFile('file')){
        // Get filename with the extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ext
        $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Filename to store
        $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        // Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/file', $fileNameToStore);

       return redirect()->back() ->with('alert', 'Updated!');
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
    }

}
```

Comment: I know all this, I'm asking if it's necessary to do 'hasFile()' and 'isValid()' after I've already validated it..

Comment: I dont know what are you trying to do

Comment: If you have validated it by some other means simply do the following   $request->file->store('files');   Where file is your Folder name

Comment: i don't know, it wasn't me

Comment: Later I had specified in the comment.. even i dont know who downvoted me